# Using GA Data Export API to Get All UA's

Tags: google-analytics-api

I am using the GA Data Export API to interact with Google Analytics and I'm making a lot of progress, I am using this URL Endpoint initially to pull all the profiles under an account:

https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/accounts/default

This URL retrieves each GA ID (profile) and each UA. One thing I've realized is one account can contain multiple UAs and when this happens, this request pulls all profiles. We have a client who has about 115 profiles under like 10 different UAs, and the request takes about 30 seconds for the initial request (and then I believe it must be cached, because it speeds up considerably after this, but then the next day the same thing occurs).

Is there a way to get a list of UA's without pulling the profiles? This way I can query the UA specifically for the profiles instead of pulling each one.

Any advice on this would be really helpful!

Thanks

UPDATE: Here's some documentation on the specific call I am using right now:

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataReferenceAccountFeed.html

UPDATE 1: I have found some interesting information in the docs

> Once your application has verified
>   that the user has Analytics access,
>   its next step is to find out which
>   Analytics accounts the user has access
>   to. Remember, users can have access to
>   many different accounts, and within
>   them, many different profiles. For
>   this reason, your application cannot
>   access any report information without
>   first requesting the list of accounts
>   available to the user. The resulting
>   accounts feed returns that list, but
>   most importantly, the list also
>   contains the account profiles that the
>   user can view.

So this means that you have to use the default accounts call to get these back? Surely, somebody has had this issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently, you can query the account if you know the UA-ID, however there is no way to get back a list of only UA IDs.

One way you can do it is have the user enter their own UA ID instead of having them choose one; not as user-friendly as it could be but better than making the user wait 30 seconds!